# Parsing json collection using play scala reads

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Assume that I have a case class:

```
case class Element(name: String)
```

and a companion class which has a reads:

```
object Element {
  implicit val elementReads = (
    (JsPath / "name").read[String]
  )
}
```

I need a map of this objects, so:

```
object ElementMap {
  def apply(elements: Iterable[Element]) = {
    val builder = Map.newBuilder[String, Element]
    elements.foreach { x => builder += ((x.name, x)) }
    builder result       
  }
}
```

Finally, I have to create a reads that would read from JSON:

```
implicit val elementMapReads = (
    (JsPath \ "elements").read[Seq[Element]]
)(ElementMap(_))
```

However I get a error message here:

```
overloaded method value read with alternatives: (t: Seq[Element])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[Element]] <and> (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[Element]])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[Element]] cannot be applied to (Iterable[Element] ⇒ Map[String,Element])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working version:

```
case class Element(name: String)

object Element {
  implicit val elementReads: Reads[Element] =
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String].map(Element.apply)

  implicit val elementMapReads: Reads[Map[String, Element]] = 
    (JsPath \ "elements").read[Seq[Element]].map(ElementMap(_))
}

object ElementMap {
  def apply(elements: Iterable[Element]) = {
    val builder = Map.newBuilder[String, Element]
    elements.foreach { x => builder += ((x.name, x)) }
    builder result       
  }
}
```

In your code, the `elementReads` implicit as it is defined is a `Reads[String]`, not a `Reads[Element]`; in general it's better to have explicit type annotations in play-json as there are some implicit conversions going on that need them.

Also, `Reads[_]` has a map method that is convenient when you have single-field wrappers and that solves also the problem of converting a `Reads[Seq[Element]]` to create a `Reads[Map[String, Element]]`.

Finally, moving the `elementMapReads` in the `Element` companion object *should* make it automatically available (i.e. no import required when using it); I didn't test it but it should work as far as I know.

Comment: Just one question - if I will have a class with a two properties (like `case class Element(name: String, amount: Int)` it should be okay with using `((JsPath \ "name").read[String] and (JsPath \ "amount").read[Int])(Element.apply(_,_) `?

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple properties that's the syntax you should use. You can also use a single underscore if you leave the parens out: `((JsPath \ "name").read[String] and (JsPath \ "amount").read[Int])(Element.apply _)`